# How can I use Automapper to map all zero int values to null values for nullable int targets?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I use `int?` for all my required 'FK' properties in ViewModels. This gives me an easy way of specifying on a Create view model that a value is nullable and must be assigned a value to satisfy the `Required` attribute.

My problem comes in because I create the domain model entity first, using a domain factory, then map it to the view model. Now, many of the nullable ints in the view model get assigned 0 from non-nullable ints in the domain model. I would prefer not to build the new entity in the view model and only map it back to the domain model to avoid his. What else can I do? i'm sure there is som Automapper voodoo that can help me.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want here, but take a look at the `Ignore` and `AllowNullDestinationValues` mapping directives. That may give you what you need.

Comment: I tried a quick sample and Automapper seems to handle mapping null reference types to nullable ints fine (assigns null to the nullable-int).  Can you show some sample code that isn't working the way you'd like?

Comment: @PatrickSteele My issue is that I'd only like that mapping to view models used for creating new entities, not ones used for editing entities. With editing, if an int is zero, I'd like to keep it zero instead of nulling it.

Comment: Wait...  You just said the exact opposite of the title of the question.  Your question says "map all zero int values to null" but your comment just said "I'd like to keep it zero instead of nulling it".  Sorry, I'm not clear on what it is you need -- is there any way you could provide some sample code?

Comment: @PatrickSteele I tried to explain in my question that this is only for create actions.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: you dont need to do any of this, but i thought i'd leave it here for people looking for a similar solution. really all you have to do is just provide a mapping from `int` to `int?` like this: `Mapper.Map<int, int?>()`

in that case, I believe you could use a custom type converter, which inherits from automappers ITypeConverter. This code works, I've run it through .NET Fiddle:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        CreateMappings();
        var vm = Mapper.Map<MyThingWithInt, MyThingWithNullInt>(new MyThingWithInt());

        if (vm.intProp.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value is not NULL!");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value is NULL!");
        }
    }

    public void CreateMappings() 
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<int, int?>().ConvertUsing(new ZeroToNullIntTypeConverter ());
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyThingWithInt, MyThingWithNullInt>();
    }


    public class ZeroToNullIntTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<int, int?>
    {
        public int? Convert(ResolutionContext ctx)
        {
           if((int)ctx.SourceValue == 0)
           {
              return null;
           }
            else
           {
               return (int)ctx.SourceValue;
           }
        }
    }

    public class MyThingWithInt
    {
        public int intProp = 0; 
    }

    public class MyThingWithNullInt
    {
        public int? intProp {get;set;}  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `.ForMember()` method on your mapping. Something like this:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.MyNullableIntProperty,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 0)
    );
```

Comment: True, but that is only valid for one mapping. I am looking for a universal solution, something like `ForMemberOfType<T>`